# Локальные экстремумы кусочно-заданной функции на отрезке, Wolfram Mathematica

Tags: mathematica

Как найти локальные минимум и максимум кусочно-заданной функции на отрезке?

Comment: в WOLFRAM Alpha все понятно, а как задать условие в mathematica?

Answer (score 0):

Задайте функцию, например вот так `F[x_] := If[x < 0, x^2 + x, x^2 - x]`, и смело пользуйтесь  `FindMinimum` и `FindMaximum`.